# Data from PHP, to XCODE LABEL.TEXT

Tags: php, xcode, text

I am trying my first xcode-project to retrieve data from a php file. The variable that I need to retrieve in the php file will be text based. The output should be outputted in a label OR textfield within my project.

I have problems with the coding and need some help with it...

This is the current structure of my php file :

```
<?php
$idwlctxt = hello;
echo $idwlctxt;
?>
```

This is my coding so far. I tried to compile it from other examples I found:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://WEBSITE/test.php?";
NSData * dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing quotes in your PHP code. You probably intended:

```
<?php
$idwlctxt = "hello";
echo $idwlctxt;
?>
```

Also, as a matter of good defensive programming, you might want to employ the rendition of `dataWithContentsOfURL` that detects errors for you:

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://WEBSITE/test.php?";
NSError  *error     = nil;
NSData   *dataURL   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] options:kNilOptions error:&error];

if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: dataWithContentsOfURL error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
else
{
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%s: result = %@", __FUNCTION__, result);

    // if you were updating a label with an `IBOutlet` called `resultLabel`, you'd do something like:

    self.resultLabel.text = result;
}
```

---

Once you get the above code to work the next logical enhancement is to use JSON (which is a better technique for passing data from PHP to your Objective-C program). The PHP code would look like:

```
<?php

$idwlctxt = "hello";

// As your PHP gets more complicated, you might want to handle errors and report
// them back to the client with a non-zero `status`, so I always return a status code.
// Clearly, this is so trivial that no error handling is needed, but it's a good
// habit to write your PHP with an eye on more extensive error handling in the future.

$response = array("status" => 0, "idwlctxt" => $idwlctxt);

echo json_encode($response);

// this should generate a response, something like:
//
//   {"status":0, "idwlctxt":"hello"}

?>
```

Next, let's parse this JSON response, and do it asynchronously so we do not block the main queue:

```
NSString     *urlString = @"https://WEBSITE/test.php?";
NSURL        *url       = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// rather than using `dataWithContentsOfURL`, let's use NSURLConnection to do an asynchronous request,
// so that the request doesn't block the main queue

// first, make the NSURLRequest

NSURLRequest *request   = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

// now, let's send that request asynchronously

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    // first, check to see if there was an error with sendAsynchronousRequest

    if (connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"%s: sendAsynchronousRequest error: %@", __FUNCTION__, connectionError);
        return;
    }

    // you generally don't do this conversion of the data to a string,
    // but it's useful to use this technique if you are diagnosing problems with your JSON
    //
    // NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // NSLog(@"%s: raw JSON = %@", __FUNCTION__, jsonString);

    // now, let's parse the JSON

    NSError *parseError = nil;
    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&parseError];

    if (parseError) {
        NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, parseError);
        return;
    }

    // now, let's extract our data from the JSON

    NSNumber *status   = results[@"status"];
    NSString *idwlctxt = results[@"idwlctxt"];
    NSLog(@"%s: status = %@; idwlctxt = %@", __FUNCTION__, status, idwlctxt);

    self.resultLabel.text = idwlctxt;
}];
```

There are other possible enhancements, but I fear I may have already thrown too much at you, so I'll stop here.

Comment: Hey hey Rob.... Im up to the challenge :) no need to fear, Tommy Is here ! Lets Get this coding on track the frist 24 h. I am unable to get to my php because its on a protected hosting service. I need to do the authentication challenge but need example coding to get me through. The nslog shows me the html code for a login script when running script This Should be an easy basic authentication, but were do i implent it? Thanks in advance...

Comment: @TommyFierens In my "other possible enhancements", I was going to suggest not using `initWithRequest` (gives you more control) instead of `sendAsynchronousRequest`. See [URL Loading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) guide. You then have to handle [Authentication Challenges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/AuthenticationChallenges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009507-SW1).

Comment: @TommyFierens By the way, my comment assumes that the server is using basic challenge-response authentication (this is fairly common). You might want to update your question with the particulars of what your HTTP server told you to do if it doesn't appear to be standard challenge-response authentication.

Comment: One of the best answers I have ever seen on SO. Great Job!